# Pass javascript string variable to another page and get the variable in PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I basically don't seem to understand sending a variable to another page.
I've tried PHP sessions, javascript cookies and ajax POST and GET.
I'm trying to send the innerHTML of a div, with the data created by a jQuery call,
a variable called `savedartists`. It displays correctly in the console.log on the sending page but the `$_POST['savedArtists']`
is undefined in the receiving page. I have spent hours looking at different posts on this site but I haven't been able to get it to work.
Any help is appreciated.

```
<input class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 et_pb_bg_layout_light" onClick="savequote();" type="button" id="savedchoices" value="Commander la prestation" >

<script>
function savequote() {
    var savedartists = document.getElementById('selectedList').innerHTML;
    console.log(savedartists);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/',
        data: { savedArtists : savedartists },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success!");
            location.href = "example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

On the receiving page (example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['savedArtists']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['savedArtists'];
    echo $uid;
} else {
    echo 'zit!';
}
?>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Take a step back... Why are you using AJAX for this in the first place?  Currently you are making *two requests* to the target URL.  The first is an AJAX POST request which contains the data you want but ignores the result.  The second is a standard GET request (redirecting the user to another page) which does not contain any data.  What's the actual goal here?  Do you want to redirect the user to that page?  If so, what's the purpose of the AJAX request?  If the value should be in a POST and you want to redirect the user, why use JavaScript at all?  Why not just put the value in a form?

Comment: What do you mean : "but ignores the result". I'm trying to use Ajax because the data to be sent is in a javascript variable.
If I use a form, should I write something like < input type="text" name="name" value="<script>document.write(variable)</script>">

Comment: The `success` callback in the jQuery `.ajax()` function is where you handle the response from the AJAX request.  The first argument passed to that function (in this case the `data` variable) is the response from the server.  The code shown does nothing with that response.  The result from the server is ignored.  What the code does is log a hard-coded value to the console and then redirect the user to a page.  So the question remains... What exactly do you *want* to happen here?  Do you want to keep the user on the same page?  Redirect the user to another page?  Currently you're mixing both.

Comment: I want to redirect to the other page.

Comment: Then AJAX is not the tool you want.  A standard HTML form would be used to direct the user to another page with a POST request.  You can use JavaScript to manipulate the form elements/values if you need to, though it's not known from the information provided if you need to.  But start simple... Create a form that posts values to the target page.  From there, start adding/changing features as needed.  But at a high level, if you want to redirect the user to another page then AJAX is simply the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @David  I did what you said and it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing as an answer for future readers...

Fundamentally what's happening here is that *two* requests are being made to the target page.  The first one is the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/',
    data: { savedArtists : savedartists },
    success: function(data) {
        //...
    }
});
```

This is a POST request which contains the data you expect, and works just fine.  *However*, the result of this request is being ignored.  That result is available in the `success` callback, but the code doesn't do anything with it:

```
console.log("success!");
location.href = "example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/";
```

Instead, what the code is doing is performing a redirect.  This creates a *second* request to that same page (though it's essentially irrelevant that it's the same page).  This is a GET request and contains no data to send to the server.

At its simplest, you should *either* use AJAX *or* redirect the user.  Currently you're mixing both.

> I want to redirect to the other page.

In that case AJAX is the wrong tool for the job.  You may not even need JavaScript at all, unless you want to modify the elements/values of a form before submitting that form.  But if all you want is to POST data to another page while directing the user to that page, a plain old HTML form does exactly that.  For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/">
  <input type="text" name="savedArtists">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this case whatever value the user enters into the `<input>` will be included in the POST request to `example.com/artiste/mise-en-relation/` when the user submits the form.